# d3.js - Add Chart Legend in a Single Line

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, d3.js

I want to add legend in my chart in a single line using `rect` and `text`. It has four items. I tried with the below code. But it displays each item line by line only.

```
var ChartId = '#' + Id;
var LegendId = '#' + Id + 'Legend';
var size = 20;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(['#1A9AD4', '#10B981', '#F59E0B',
        '#EF4444', '#bf6fe7', '#eb5b5b', '#607d8b',
        '#80B300', '#809900', '#E6B3B3', '#6680B3', '#66991A',
        '#FF99E6', '#CCFF1A', '#FF1A66', '#E6331A', '#33FFCC',
        '#66994D', '#B366CC', '#4D8000', '#B33300', '#CC80CC',
        '#66664D', '#991AFF', '#E666FF', '#4DB3FF', '#1AB399',
        '#E666B3', '#33991A', '#CC9999', '#B3B31A', '#00E680',
        '#4D8066', '#809980', '#E6FF80', '#1AFF33', '#999933',
        '#FF3380', '#CCCC00', '#66E64D', '#4D80CC', '#9900B3',
        '#E64D66', '#4DB380', '#FF4D4D', '#99E6E6', '#6666FF'
    ]);
$(LegendId).remove();
$(ChartId).parent().append('<div id="' + Id + 'Legend" style="width:15%"></div>');
var StatusAccessor = function (d) {
    return d.key[1];
}
var filteredData = Grps;  //.all();
var Status = d3.set(filteredData.map(StatusAccessor)).values();
var svg2 = d3.select(LegendId)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 140)
    .attr("height", 250);
var legend = svg2.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(SortInOrder(Status.slice().reverse(), SortArray))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(5," + i * 22 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 2)
    .attr("y", 10) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    .attr("width", size)
    .attr("height", size)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d) })

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 28)
    .attr("y", 19) // 100 is where the first dot appears. 25 is the distance between dots
    //.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d) })
    .text(function (d) { return d.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "") })
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
```

I tried below style. Still it's not working.

```
.legend {
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can adjust `translate()` as below to make it in a single line:

```
var legend = svg2.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(SortInOrder(Status.slice().reverse(), SortArray))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {        
        if (d == "Alert Task")
            return "translate(" + i * 143 + ", 0 )";
        else
            return "translate(" + i * 100 + ", 0 )";
    });
```